# Calling a ngDialog from within ngDialog controller not working

Tags: angularjs, ng-dialog

I have an ngDialog modal which shows an uploaded image and allows users to comment. This is how I call it:

```
$scope.openShowPic = function (imageName, imagedescription, username, imagelikeslength, comments, imageid) {
$scope.imageName = imageName;
        $scope.imageDescription = imagedescription;
        $scope.username = username;
        $scope.imagelikeslength = imagelikeslength;
        $scope.comments = comments;
        $scope.imageid = imageid;

        ngDialog.open({ template: 'views/showpic.html', scope: $scope, 
            className: 'ngdialog-theme-mine dialogwidth800', controller:"ShowPicController" });
    };
```

If the user's token expires before they submit the comments I have an error handler which detects a 401 error status and then makes sure the user is logged out and closes the showPic ngDialog. It then opens the login ngDialog so the user can login.

```
$scope.submitComment = function () {

        CommentFactory.save({id: $scope.imageid}, $scope.mycomment)
        .$promise.then(
              function (response) {
                console.log(response);
              },
              function (error) {
                console.log('error');

                if (error.status == 401){

                   AuthFactory.logout();
                   $scope.loggedIn = false;
                   $scope.username = '';
                   ngDialog.close();

                    ngDialog.open({ template: 'views/login.html', scope: $scope, 
                    className: 'ngdialog-theme-default', controller:"LoginController" });
                  }
              }); 

        $scope.commentForm.$setPristine();

        $scope.mycomment = {
            comment: ""
        };

    };
```

Unfortunately the login ngDialog is not communicating with the LoginController as nothing happens when the user clicks to login. The code to call the login ngDialog is exactly the same as I use in the header and which works fine.
Obviously I have broken something but cannot see what!
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK I tried to get the login ngDialog working from inside the error part of promise.then but to no avail. In the end I found the best way of tackling this was to set a boolean value in the error function and then open the login ngDialog depending on the result of the boolean value.

```
$scope.submitComment = function () {
        $scope.needLogin = false;
        CommentFactory.save({id: $scope.imageid}, $scope.mycomment)
        .$promise.then(
              function (response) {
                console.log(response);
              },
              function (error) {
                console.log('error');

                if (error.status == 401){

                   AuthFactory.logout();
                   $scope.loggedIn = false;
                   $scope.username = '';
                   $scope.needLogin = true;
                  }
              }); 

        $scope.commentForm.$setPristine();

        $scope.mycomment = {
            comment: ""
        };
        if ($scope.needLogin == true) {
            ngDialog.open({ template: 'views/login.html', scope: $scope, 
                className: 'ngdialog-theme-default', controller:"LoginController" });
        };      
    };           
}])
```